# My image is being scaled as ridiculously small

Tags: graphics, png

I am in hurry, therefore I decided that to make a list describing what different icons do in my program, I'll use this simple code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label= ,leftmargin=*]
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{stopped} Robot je zakázán a nebude provádět žádné akce.
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{paused} Robot je povolen ale momentálně neběží.
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{running} Robot běží. Bude-li zakázán jeho běh bude přerušen.
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{stopped_error} Robot byl deaktivován kvůli opakované chybě.
\end{enumerate}
```

Where the graphics are $16\times16$ png images:

[image: image description]

For some reason, this is the result:

[image: screenshot of list with images in it]

One of the png images is getting scaled insanely small. In the output I see:

```
<paused.png, id=85, 0.93706pt x 0.93706pt>
File: paused.png Graphic file (type png)
<use paused.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: paused.png used on input line 150.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 0.74963pt x 0.74963pt.
```

Why? All the images are [available online](https://github.com/Darker/auto-client/tree/master/resources), I am just translating some docs from [my project's GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Darker/auto-client/wiki/Passive-automation#icon-indicators).

Comment: Try with `\includegraphics[width=2ex]{running}` instead of `scale`. Adjust `2ex` suitably.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. But are you able to explain the problem to me please? As all the images were the same size and had the same scale defined, it's really interesting in my opinion.

Comment: ...or, alternately, use `[height=\ht\strutbox]` as the optional argument,

Comment: The problem is that the native size of your icons are not all identical,  Scaling is applied to the native size, whereas `width` and `height` define the final LaTeX size.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am unsure what you mean by native size. The pixel dimensions are the same, the file size isn't. Could you please elaborate? I'd gladly accept and upvote an answer that describes and explains it.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/, table 4.1. In addition to the pixel size, png allows for a specification of the physical dimensions of a pixel.  Thus, two 16x16 images could present as two completely different physical sizes (see also section 11.3.5.3 of the same document).

Comment: @Tomas, I'd say that even if two images have the same number of pixels, those are not necessarily equally translated to centimeters/inches. The "resolution" is the relation between pixels and physical measures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_resolution

Answer (score 8):

Harish asked me to provide the answer to this question.  The OP notes that several png images, all 16x16 pixels, display at vastly different sizes in his document.

To the OP, several comments were made.  First, Harish suggested how to fix the problem, by using the `width=` specifier to `\includegraphics`, rather than the `scale=` specifier.  I mentioned that one could also use the `height` specifier in the form of `[height=\ht\strutbox]` to achieve a fixed height that would fit on a line (without interfering with line spacing).  I noted that "The problem is that the native size of your icons are not all identical, Scaling is applied to the native size, whereas width and height define the final LaTeX size."

In a later comment, I noted that the png specification allows for pixels of various size, so that not all 16x16 images necessarily present the same way.  See table 4.1 excerpted from the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) Specification (Second Edition) http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/:

[image]

A zoom of this table shows the key row:

[image]

indicating that the physical size of a pixel is part of the png specification

Later in that document, elaboration is given on how the physical pixel size is specified in the image encoding.

[image]

Comment: Nice references ;).